# How to know which python class I'm editing in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I usually have to work with big python files which contain several classes. It's not unusual that when I'm editing a file, I don't know which class I'm working in, and it would be great if I could hover or right click on a method and directly know which class it belongs to without having to scroll all the way up.

Is there any sublime text 3 plugin or trick to do that ?

Comment: This sounds like something that would be available in a fully featured IDE, not a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/), which tries to make a python IDE of your sublime text 3. But I'm not sure it covers what you are looking for.

Nontheless it has some nice features like autocompletion, imports checking, PEPE style checks.

Another option could be to check [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), which is a more extensive Python IDE.